# error creating android device in trigger.io

Tags: android, sdk, device

when trying to

Error creating Android Virtual Device

I have the current android sdk tools installed and had its location referenced.

This same sdk toolkit has provent to work with eclipse.

Below are the notifications of a single running attempt.

How to fix the problem?

Greetings
T

run android
tools running at version 3.3.17
Update result: you already have the latest tools
WARNING No profile DEFAULT found for android
Checking  files...
check complete
Verifying your configuration settings...
Configuration settings check complete
Development build created. Use  run to run your app.
 tools running at version 3.3.17
WARNING No profile DEFAULT found for android
Checking  files...
check complete
Verifying your configuration settings...
Configuration settings check complete
Starting ADB if not running
Looking for Android device
Checking for previously created AVD
ERROR Error creating Android Virtual Device. Attempting to update Android SDK and retry
Updating SDK and downloading required Android platform (about 90MB, may take some time)
Attempting to create Android Virtual Device again
ERROR Error creating Android Virtual Device: Error: Target id is not valid. Use 'android.bat list targets' to get the target ids.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an Android platform installed. If you select the `Show Debug` option in the trigger.io UI when you run the project, then you should see the actual line that is trying to create the AVD. In my case it was:

```
android.bat create avd -n forge -t android-8 --skin HVGA -p...
```

Go to your SDK install folder and run the SDK Manager exe. You can then select the correct packages to install. In my case I selected Android 2.2 (API-8), after which the above line to create the AVD worked fine and trigger.io fired up the emulator.